# Sequelize afterFind hook not changing data in console.log?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to run afterFind hook on a model, but the result doesn't seem to change in console.log with JSON.stringify after I run the query. However, the data is changed if I specifically log the attribute.

```
// on User model
User.hook('afterFind', function(result) {
    result.teamCount = 1
    return result.save()
  }
})
```

Then when I try to log it:

```
const result = await User.find()
console.log(result.teamCount) // -> 1
console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) // no "teamCount" attribute present
```

Not sure what the hook is doing or if `save()` is even required but something seems off, how can I make the change visible in console.log?

Comment: Which version of sequelize are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the teamCount field as virtual:

```
sequelize.define('user', {
   ...
   teamCount: {
      type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL
   }
   ...
});
```